# Why can't some Linux processes use pstree printing?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system

I'm completing an assignment which is about realize a `pstree` command on Linux,my basic idea is to Traverse the files in the `/proc` directory and look through the `/proc/pid/status` and `/proc/pid/task` to see the relationships between different processes,however,when i traverse the files,i notice that some processes are not showing up on the shell after `pstree` command,i don't how to solve this

for example:`/proc/2/status` is:

```
Name:   kthreadd
Umask:  0000
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   2
Ngid:   0
Pid:    2
PPid:   0
....
```

but i use command `pstree -p|grep kthreadd` ,the `pstree` command couldn't find the `kthreadd` processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> All kernel threads are descendants of kthreadd (pid 2), which is
> spawned by the kernel (pid 0) during boot. The kthreadd enumerates
> other kernel threads; it provides interface routines through which
> other kernel threads can be dynamically spawned at runtime by kernel
> services. Kernel threads can be viewed from the command line with the
> ps -ef command--they are shown in [square brackets]:
> ```

[Kernel threads](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/cloud-and-networking/9781785883057/1/ch01lvl1sec13/kernel-threads)

As PID 2 is not a descendent of PID 1, it's not in the display of pstree.

Comment: thanks a lot , however , I try to trace the running of pstree by using strace command , and I notice It also opened the /proc/pid directory ,and I wonder how did the Linux ignore pid2, pid3(child of pid2)... and get the process that needs output?